# Is Vagrant an operating system by itself?

Tags: vagrant

If Vagrant (and similar software) uses to orchestrate, install and continuously upgrade one or more OSs on a single machine, isn't it some kind of an operating system by itself?

Or it actually virtualizes an OS **on top of an existing OS** and doesn't operate as an OS by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Vagrant is a tool for creating virtual environments, which it then can run inside a virtual machine (originally only using Virtualbox, but nowadays also KVM and VMware among others).

The environment created by Vagrant is, however, a fully virtualized OS (e.g. Ubuntu).